# Angular 6 Scroll Listener Reloads Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

To lay this out as simply as possible, here's my scenario.

1) I have parent component that has a `ViewContainerRef` to dynamically load in a component within the parent. For my use case, the parents is an empty holder page that replaces itself dynamically with another page dependent on a set of variables.

`<ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>`

2) The child component has a horizontal scroll div that looks similar to the following:

`<div id="carousel" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <!-- List of components -->
</div>`

Any time it is scrolled WITH the `(scroll)` listener, it reloads the parent component and therefore the scroll position always bounces back to 0 because it was reloaded.

However, if I remove the `(scroll)` listener the div scrolls without an issue. The problem is, I want to dynamically change items on the page based on the horizontal scroll position.

Does anyone have any thoughts on issues that could arise with embedded components and a scroll listener? Would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: what does onScroll() do?

Comment: All it does right now is console.log the event, nothing else. Even when nothing is in the function it behaves this way @GreyBeardedGeek

Comment: The presence of the `(scroll)` event handler triggers change detection every time the `div` is scrolled. We should see the rest of the markup and code to find if change detection causes a reload of the component.

Comment: To test the hypothesis of my previous comment: (1) remove the `(scroll)` event handler, (2) in the constructor or `ngOnInit`, call `setInterval(() => { this.applicationRef.tick(); }, 5000)`, which forces change detection every 5 seconds, (3) scroll the div and check if the component is reloaded when change detection occurs.

Comment: Did you try using renderer and viewchild to subscribe to onscroll event?

Comment: @karoluS How would I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Doing what you suggested essentially crashed my Chrome and couldn't really do much testing. Perhaps I implemented it incorrectly, however.

Comment: Make sure that you injected `ApplicationRef`: `constructor(private applicationRef: ApplicationRef) { ... }`, and check the console to see if any error is reported when testing.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the `onScroll` is triggering Angular's change detector (like the comments suggest), which for some reason decides the page is dirty -- which triggers a redraw of the page. If that is the case, I suspect the redraw resets the carousel div.

To confirm this suspicion you can change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` on your troublesome component. `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` **will only redraw your component if the data bound to an `@Input()` (like `data` bellow) changes OR if you explicitly tell it too**.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-neat',
  templateUrl: './neat.component.html',
  // Add this line to your component
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush 
})
export class NeatComponent {
  @Input() data: string[];
}
```

That means that when you do want the component to redraw you need to explicitly tell Angular to do so. You can do that like so:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-neat',
  templateUrl: './neat.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data: string[];

  // Inject the ChangeDetectorRef into your component
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  refresh() {
    // Manually tell Angular to detect changes and redraw the screen
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```

You can find more info here: https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/

This should allow you to have fine grained control over what content on your page redraws when the scroll event is triggered.

If you post more code, we might be able to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: oh, after hours of searching, this was the solution to my problem...thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are injecting components like this but this is my try to take this problem.

I used renderer to listen to window event scroll in child component.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfpfxp)

*Don't mind my styling*

Answer (score 0):

If you use window object direcly from child component it will give zero always

since you want to use window scroll event from child you can use event object to get the ScrollY value

**Child.html**

```
 <p (window:scroll)="onScroll($event)" >
    demo Scroll Value{{scrollValue}}
    </p>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
 onScroll($e){
    this.scrollValue=$e.path[1].scrollY;
    console.log($e.path[1].scrollY);
  }
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/viewcontainer

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
  onWindowScroll() {
    let scrollTop = (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
    let clientHeight =  document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    let scrollHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
    if ((scrollTop + clientHeight) >= scrollHeight) {
       //FUNCTIONS WHEN BOTTOM
    }
    else if ((scrollTop + scrollHeight) == scrollHeight) {
       //FUNCTIONS WHEN TOP
    }
  }
```